# String quotation marks when exporting a Mathematica Grid as vector graphics

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Running the following

```
agrid = Grid[{{Style["hello", Bold]}}]
ImportString[ExportString[agrid, "PNG"], "PNG"]
ImportString[ExportString[agrid, "EPS"], "EPS"]
```

spits out

> **hello**
>    **hello**
>   **"hello"**

That is, the EPS exporter included the quotation marks in the output. Same for PDF. Without the `Grid`, all exporters leave out the quotation marks.
What magic do I need to get rid of the quotation marks in the PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add ShowStringCharacters->False to your Style.

Comment: Thanks, I was not looking in that direction at all. Do you know of  any reason it works fine (without fancy styling) when the string is not in a Grid?

Comment: @Janus The reason is that [export to PDF uses the `"Printout"` screen style environment by default](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/7f5cb9e2d4677855) but export to raster formats seems to be using the default `"Working"` environment. An alternative to `ShowStringCharacters->False` is to set `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]` as suggested by Mr.Wizard [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093559/how-to-export-graphics-in-working-style-environment-rather-than-printout/6093783#6093783).